# How to use wildcards with directories in PowerShell's Get-ChildItem -Exclude cmdlet

Tags: powershell, directory, get-childitem

For a simple example, let's say I have a folder, `Root`, with three folders in it; Folder1, Folder2, and Folder3. Each of these folders (including `Root`) has a bunch of files in them, including .pdb files. I want to use the [PowerShell Get-ChildItem cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) to return all of the files in all of the folders (including `Root`), except for the .pdb files in Folder2. If I use:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Root -Recurse -Exclude *.pdb
```

Then I get back all of the non-.pdb files in all of the directories, which is close to what I want. So I assumed that the following would achieve what I want:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Root -Recurse -Exclude \*\\Folder2\\*.pdb
```

But this does not exclude any of the pdb files in Folder2 (or any other folders). I have tried several variants for the `-Exclude` filter, such as `Folder2\\\*.pdb`, but I cannot get it to work. In fact, even using `\*\\\*.pdb` does not seem to do anything; no .pdb files get excluded from any folders.

So it seems that the wildcards cannot be used for directories, only filenames, but I assume I am just doing something wrong. I found [this article explaining the wildcard and range operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692793.aspx), but unfortunately it does not discuss using them with directory names; only file names.

Answer (score 12):

I haven't seen the exclude parameter working with directories either.

You could try piping into [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx). That is,

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.pdb | Where-Object {$_.FullName -notMatch "folder2"}
```

Comment: No, this isn't what I'm looking for. It would return ONLY the .pdb files that aren't in Folder2, but I want ALL of the files, except for the .pdb files that are in Folder2. But you may be on path for a possible solution by piping into Where-Object; although I would still like to know how to use the wildcard character with directories (or if it's just not possible).

Answer (score 6):

OhadH's answer is almost there.

You can use

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.FullName -notmatch "folder2" -or $_.Name -notlike "*.pdb" }
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? {$_.FullName -notlike "*folder2*" -or $_.Name -notlike "*.pdb" }
```

It depends on where your folder2 is located. But I think you got the idea.

I hate to say it, but PowerShell is not any convenient as [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) or other shells.

Answer (score 5):

```
 gci "C:\Root" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.FullName -notlike "*Folder2\*.pdb*"} | Export-CSV "C:\Root\Export.csv" -NoType
```

Tried, tested & one liner :-). This works as I have copied your folder & file structure to replicate. Sorry about it being a few years late, however.

Feel free to tweak the code to your needs, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Use asterisk and recursion parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\"
              -Filter "*config*" -Recurse | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be work for you:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Root -Exclude "*\Folder2\*.pdb" -Recurse
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work.  Still just returns all .pdb files in all folders.